# import in actionscript 3. CS4 to CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I want to create a waterfall in flash cs6. I found this waterfall from http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/waterfall/

```
import com.flashandmath.dg.display.*;

var waterfall:Waterfall;

init();
function init():void {
    waterfall = new Waterfall(200,300,true);
waterfall.x = 20;
waterfall.y = 10;
stage.addChild(waterfall);
waterfall.startFlow();


waterfall.noSplashes = false;
waterfall.dropsToAddEachFrame = 8;
waterfall.targetColor = 0x33B2FF;
waterfall.waterTopWidth = 72;
waterfall.leftMargin = 2;
waterfall.minAngle = Math.PI/12;
waterfall.maxAngle = Math.PI/3;
waterfall.minMagnitude = 0.7;
waterfall.maxMagnitude = 1.3;
waterfall.fadeAmount = -1;
waterfall.display.minGray = 0.9;


}
```

This is from a cs4 file. I tried to save that as a cs6 or cs5 and i got this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 11  1172: Definition com.flashandmath.dg.display could not be found.
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work or if possible how to make it work?

Comment: Well, you don't have that package as a resource in your project. You'll need to get that resource and add it in File>ActionScript Settings as a library

Comment: @Koiski your response should be as an answer not a comment.  And Josh, you should accept that answer as your solution.  That way this question appears as answered and accepted and people will be able to reference it for help later, and people looking for questions to answer don't keep opening this one thinking its an unsolved problem. :)

Comment: @JoshJanusch if you post this as an answer, I will accept it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the package (`com.flashandmath.dg.display`) in your project. To do so, add it to the library section of `File>ActionScript Settings`